# Prolog - Deleting Nth Column From A Matrix

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a query `elimcol(_, [H|T], X)` that deletes the nth column in a matrix array.

I believe that I'm complicating things as a beginner, but in Prolog logic, it would be better to call a matrix a "list of lists". So with that being said, since columns are essentially the "ith" element in every list of list, how would one go about deleting the ith element from all the lists, in a list of of lists. (I'm sorry for this confusing statement)

So far, this is what I was able to create:

```
elimcol(1, [G|H], H) :- !.
elimcol(N, [G|H], [G|L]) :- 
    N > 1, 
    Nn is N - 1,
    !,
    elimcol(Nn,H,L).
```

This is able to delete for one list. However when I tried to expand deleting more lists, it doesn't seem to delete the "ith element" anymore.

```
?- elimcol(3,[[1,2,3], [1,1,1], [4,5,6]], X).
X = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]].
```

Appreciate any help on this. Many thanks!

EDIT: Did some minor changes, however same result i'm still only able to delete ith elements for (just one list)

```
elimcol(_, [], []).
elimcol(1, [_|T], T) :- !.
elimcol(I, [H|T], [H|R]) :-
   I1 is I-1,
   !, 
   elimcol(I1, T, R).
```

Comment: Decompose the problem. As you note, what you want to do is to apply the same operation (deletion of the i-th element) to each list. So first write a predicate that does this deletion of the i-th element of a list. Only afterwards write a second predicate that applies the first one to each row of a matrix.

Comment: Hi sir, following your thought flow process, I believe that my predicate fulfills the first decomposition flow (deletion of the ith element of a list). My question is wouldn't a second predicate make transferring the value (that I've obtained from one to another) impossible? (Since there's 2 predicates)

Many thanks!


Working for single list ith element deletion
```
?- elimcol(2, [1,2,3,4,5,6], X).
X = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6].
```

Comment: You transfer data between predicates by calling one predicate from the other. Really, write the "delete the i-th element of a list" predicate first. Add the code to your question using the edit button. Then we can help you figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maplist/N it's an idiomatic way to prove a relation among multiple lists elements,
and nth1/4 can be used to discard the column from a row. Then

```erlang
del_mat_col(M,N,M1) :-
    maplist(del_col(N),M,M1).
del_col(N,R,R1) :- nth1(N,R,_,R1).
```

yields

```erlang
?- M=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,j]],del_mat_col(M,1,M1).
M = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, j]],
M1 = [[b, c], [e, f], [h, j]].

?- M=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,j]],del_mat_col(M,2,M1).
M = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, j]],
M1 = [[a, c], [d, f], [g, j]].
```

Using library(yall), the code becomes:

```erlang
del_mat_col(M,N,M1) :-
    maplist({N}/[R,R1]>>nth1(N,R,_,R1),M,M1).
```